Joomla website using RSForms Pro not sending emails after changing hosting
We've recently take charge of hosting a client's Joomla website from another agency.
Since switching the hosting last Wednesday (22/05/24) the contact forms no longer send emails after  submission.
We're not sure what host was being used before but we're using Hostinger for this site. We're generally a WordPress based agency using WPMUDEV for hosting, who are fabulous with helping with development issues. Hostinger support for Joomla has been unhelpful at best so far unless it's server specific.
The website is being pointed from 123-reg to Hostinger's server rather than using their nameservers (to protect their email setup). I can't see any SMTP set up in the back end of the website. reCAPTCHA set up has been reconfigured as I read that can cause some issues.
Any insight would be much appreciated!
The website is being pointed from 123-reg to Hostinger's server rather than using their nameservers (to protect their email setup). I can't see any SMTP set up in the back end of the website. reCAPTCHA set up has been reconfigured as I read that can cause some issues.
